# Session en PHP se abre en todos lados

Tags: php, session, cookies

No tengo mucho tiempo que inicié mi desarrollo en PHP, y ahora manejando sesiones me ha surgido un problema que no he podido solucionar hasta el momento.

Estoy desarrollando un sitio con PHP 7.2 donde los usuarios se tienen que loguear para acceder a sus datos.
El problema es que, tanto en mi ambiente local (con xampp) como en el servidor donde estoy subiendo el proyecto, cuando realizo un login de usuario, de alguna manera se inicia de manera general, es decir: puedo hacer login en mi navegador de mi equipo local, y cualquiera que ingrese a la página ya sea en mi red, o desde cualquier parte del mundo (literalmente), ingresa como si ya hubiese estado logueado, con el mismo usuario con el que yo inicié sesión (incluso usando navegación privada).

En resumidas palabras, al iniciar sesión en cualquier lugar, se inicia de manera "general" y cualquiera que ingrese a la página ingresa como logueado con ese ususario, y lo mismo al cerrar sesión, cualquiera que la cierre cierra sesión para todo el mundo.

Este es parte de mi código que maneja sesiones:
Al inicializar las sesiones en mis páginas, uso:

```
session_id("sessionID");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200");
session_start();
```

Cuando el usuario se loguea correctamente, lo establezco asi:

```
...
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
...
```

En las páginas, verifico que esté logueado de esta manera:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
   ...
   //no está logueado
} else {
   ...
   //está logueado
}
```

Y al borrar la sesión, lo aplico así:

```
session_id("sessionID");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200");
session_start();
...
session_unset();  
setcookie(session_name(), 0, 1 , ini_get("session.cookie_path")); 
session_destroy(); 
...
```

Pero como les menciono, tengo ese problema que aún no puedo resolver, podrían ayudarme diciéndome qué estoy haciendo mal, o qué cómo se debería manejar en estos casos en los que cada cliente debe de tener sesiones independientes.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar más información de tu proyecto, como lo haces para autenticar y como eccedes a la sección de usuario y administración?

Answer (score 0):

prueba quitando el:

```
session_id("sessionID");
```

Y para borrar:

```
session_unset();  
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

- session_unset -> libera todas la variables de sesión.
- session_destroy -> borra todas las variables de sesión.
- session_regenerate_id -> actualiza el id de sesión.

Comment: La situación es que también manejo dos tipos de sesiones diferentes, para dos secciones de la página. Una es para la página de Usuarios y otra para la página de Administradores. Y leí que para manejar diferentes sesiones en un mismo sitio, habría que establecer IDs diferentes, por eso el session_id. 
Si le quito session_id, de qué otra forma podría manejar esa situación?

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías manejar las secciones por rol de usuario y guardando ese rol en una sesión, $_SESSION['rol'].

Answer (score 0):

session_start(); siempre tiene que estar primero que todo, quiza ese sea el error, proba y despues conta

```
session_start();
session_id("sessionID");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","7200");
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","7200");
```